# Does every $\mathbb{Q}$-module contain a copy of $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: group-theory, modules, rational-numbers

Every abelian group is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module. I was curious what it would take for one to also be a $\mathbb{Q}$-module. This would mean in particular that an element of the group would have to multiplied by fractions $1/n$, and associativity of scalar multiplication requires that for any $g \in G$,
$$
n \left(\frac{1}{n} \left( g \right) \right) = \left( n \cdot \frac{1}{n} \right) g = 1_\mathbb{Q} g = g
$$
Therefore, for every integer $n > 0$ and $g \in G$, there must be an element $h$ such that $nh = g$. Equivalently, the map $f_n : G \to G$ sending $g \mapsto ng$ must be a surjection. It follows immediately that $G$ cannot be a periodic group; otherwise $f_{e}$ (where $e$ is the exponent of $G$) would send every $g$ to $1_G$. In particular, it contains an isomorphic copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ via the embedding $n \mapsto n \cdot 1_G$. My question is, does it also contain an isomorphic copy of $\mathbb{Q}$? It seems intuitively clear that it must, since it contains the integers and also must contain a multiplicative inverse of every integer -- i.e. an element $n^{-1} = \frac{1}{n} \cdot 1_G$ such that $n \cdot n^{-1} = n^{-1} + \cdots + n^{-1} = 1$. However, I can imagine that maybe for some groups $G$ there are other constructions that add in such inverses without ending up with an embedding of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: $\Bbb Q$ is a field: this means that $\Bbb Q$-modules are vector spaces. In particular, every nonzero vector space has a space of dimension $1$, which is isomorphic to $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Abelian groups that are $\mathbb{Q}-modules are called *divisible* groups since, as you pointed out, their elements must be "divisible" by nonzero integers.

Comment: What about the divisible group $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$? Does this imply that it contains an isomorphic copy of $\mathbb{Q}$ itself?

Comment: @ChrisLeary: But not every divisible group is a $\mathbb{Q}$-module: The Prufer $p$-group is not a (unital) $\mathbb{Q}$-module.

Comment: @jwimberley: $\mathbb{Q}$-modules are divisible, but the converse does not hold: a (unital) $\mathbb{Q}$-module (i.e., a vector space) cannot have torsion, since $nx=0$ for $n\neq 0$ implies $x=\frac{1}{n}(nx) = 0$. Again: $\mathbb{Q}$-modules just means "vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$".

Comment: @Arturo Magidin - Of course. One of the delightful features of divisible groups is that they come in both torsion and torsion-free flavors. Not being sure of the OP's background, I left it at the case with which they were concerned. Good to hear from you again.

Comment: @ChrisLeary: The reason I commented is that when you said "are called *divisible groups*", it seemed to imply that "divisible group" was a synonym for "$\mathbb{Q}$-module", as opposed to saying "Abelian groups that are $\mathbb{Q}$-modules will necessarily be "divisible groups", which are groups that `blah`".

Comment: @ArturoMagidin - I understand your concern. After posting, I was thinking that I probably should have pointed out the existence of torsion divisible groups, got back onto MSE to post that, and discovered your note. But again, being unsure of OP's background ... . All is well here.